# What does mean com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[17.0.0] as no versions available

Tags: android, maven, google-analytics, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have offline maven repo with my organization. I am trying to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0`. I take this repo from maven and uploaded it into the our local repo.

I am not able to download the submodule.
I have added an implementation in my android project `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I am getting an error as below.

> Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[17.0.0] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl are available.

I have checked `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl` with version `17.0.0` is available in my local repo.

Now, here the question is what is the meaning of the square bracket which I am getting in error with version.?

Is that something I missed here to upload?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `play-services-analytics` depends on `play-services-analytics-impl` to work.
If you want to work with your offline repository, you should as well add dependencies of `play-services-analytics` to your own repository. Check the pom.xml file of `play-services-analytics` to see what dependencies are required.

Comment: I have added "play-services-analytics-impl" into the local repo but its says it does not found. I am very curious about square bracket. what does it mean and why it its coming like this..!!